# Does IAM policy rules attached to EC2 instance overlap(&override) policy rules attached to ECS task running within EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Below is the role assumed by EC2 instance:

```
"AScaleLaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties":{
                …..
                "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "EC2InstProfl” },
                …..
            }
        }


"EC2InstProfl": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties":{
                "Path": "/",
                "Roles": [ {  "Ref": "EC2InstRole" } ]
            }
        }


  "EC2InstRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                      {
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Principal": { "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ] },
                          "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
                      }        
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [ "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role" ],
            }
        }
```

---

Below is the `SomeTaskRole` assigned to task(docker container) running in that EC2 instance:

```
"EcsTaskDef": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties":{
                "NetworkMode": "host",
                "TaskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/SomeTaskRole",
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Name": “someapp",
                        "Image": “someaccout/someimage:test",

                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

where `SomeTaskRole` is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Description": “Allow access to all EC2/ELB/cloudformation/s3 and aim passrole",    
            …..
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Description": “Assume iam User role“,
             ….. 
           "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Description": “Assume xyz role across all accouts“,
             …..
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Description": “Allow * access to all resource across n regions",
              ….
        },
        {
            "Description": “Deny delete permission on network related resources like Subnets/Route/VPC/VPN/IGW etc…*,
              ….
        },
        {
            "Description": “There are many such rules",
              ….
        }

    ]
}
```

---

If `EC2InstRole` is assigned to EC2 instance, then Cloudformation stack gets launched successfully.

If `SomeTaskRole` is assigned to `EcsTaskDef` **and** `EC2InstRole` is assigned to EC2 instance, then Cloudformation stack launch goes for a hang for hours and error out. Yet to find the exact error. If I remove `"TaskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/SomeTaskRole"` then CloudFormation stack launches successfully.

---

1)

Does AWS IAM service allow both?

to assign role to ECS task

and

to assign role to EC2 instance?

2)

If yes, Does rules given in EC2's role overlap(& override) the rules given in ECS task's role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ECS task ONLY gets the role/permissions assigned to the task. It gets no permissions from the host.

When you see CloudFormation "hang" like this it's likely because the task(s) are never reaching a steady state. The easiest way to trouble shoot that is to look at the failed tasks in ECS. To do this open the ECS cluster, select the Tasks tab and show Stopped tasks. Open one and look at the collapsed information on the bottom. There is often some pretty helpful information there.

Comment: Are you saying that, rules mentioned in `SomeTaskRole` should work as given?

Comment: It should. I'll add some trouble shooting tips to the answer.

Comment: ECS task is not getting launched on quick troubleshooting

Comment: I already checked stopped tasks.. no entry...but still, let me re launch CFstack and check again

Comment: If the tasks aren't launching at all you may not have the correct permissions on your host. It's been a while since I used EC2 based ECS, so I can't recall what permissions are needed, but it has to be able to work with the control plane.

Comment: Tasks get launched successfully, if `SomeTaskRole` is not assigned to task.

Comment: Sounds like the role does not have a trust relationship with `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`

Comment: yes it does not have trust relationship with `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`. Because `SomeTaskRole` was previously used with EC2, now we are trying to apply to ECS task.

Comment: Do I need `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`? Which role should have trust relationship with `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`? `SomeTaskRole`?

Comment: Yes, it belongs in the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` and yes, it belongs on `SomeTaskRole`.

Comment: So, `ExecutionRoleArn` property should help assume. Isn't it? `"ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/SomeTaskRole"`. We would not need `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`. Correct me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207387/discussion-between-jason-wadsworth-and-overexchange).